# Get final special character with a regular expression

Tags: regex

i want a regular expression that groups a few special characters in the end of a string.
The special character are / - _ and the space.
For example if i have the string `(test) --- ---` i want to get the string " --- ---" in the group. 
I've created the following regular expression: `([ -\/_]*)$` 
The problem is that it get me the following string `) --- ---`
Why does extract me the final pharenthesis ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put the `-` symbol at the first or at the last inside char class Otherwise, it takes the range from space to the `/`(forward slash.) . `)` symbol also falls in that range so that it matches `)` .

```
([- \/_]+)$
```

`-` inside character class acts as a range operator only if it's not at the first or at the last or not escaped.

Comment: Ok, i didn't have clear the intervals of special characters. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

```
   ([ \-\/_]*)$
```

You should escape - so that it does not mean range.