# How do you escape a hyphen as character range in a POSIX regex

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I have a csv file full of values such as this:

```
0.00145423,3.03795e-05
```

I wanted to check that all the lines were consistent so I tried to grep for any unexpected characters like so...

```
grep '[^0-9,e\-\.]' myfile
```

In my mind it goes like this: find a line with any character `[]` that is not `^` a number `0-9`, comma `,`, letter e `e`, hyphen `\-` (**attempted to escape with `\`**), or a period `\.`. However, hyphens still continue match.

[*EDIT*]This does not happen in python, only with bash/grep:

```
>>> re.search("[^0-9,e\-\.]", "0.00145423,3.03795e-05")
>>>
```

**unsatisfying solution:**
If I move the escaped hyphen to the end it works:

```
grep '[^0-9,e\.\-]' myfile
```

Putting the escaped hyphen next to the `0-9` range results in `grep: Invalid range end`.

Can someone explain what's going on? Is this some bash argument parsing issue or something specific to grep?

`bash4.3.33`, `grep2.21`

Comment: hyphen located at the middle of character class  would act as a range operator.

Comment: @AvinashRaj I don't think this is a duplicate question. I have attempted to escape the hyphen as is proposed in both answers the [one you linked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25682967/get-final-special-character-with-a-regular-expression).

Comment: Linux regexes have to be different to any other regex engine. It's like IE, in a way.

Comment: You don't need to escape the `.` in a POSIX bracket expression since just putting the `.` in the bracket expression MEANS it's a literal character, and escaping the `-` also does nothing (as you've discovered).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The way to include a literal `-` in a character list is to put it in the first or last position of the bracket expression, exactly as shown in the answer at: [Get final special character with a regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25682967/get-final-special-character-with-a-regular-expression).

From POSIX 9.3.5 RE Bracket Expression:

> The  character shall be treated as itself if it occurs first (after an initial `^`, if any) or last in the list, or as an ending range point in a range expression.

Some tools might have additional ways of doing it with some kind of escaping but you're always safe to just put it first or last.
Note that `-` isn't the only character that has different behavior depending where it shows up in a bracket expression. Consider `]`, and `^` as well.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that `-` is a range operator, so `\-\` matches any character in the range `\` to `\`, which is exactly a `\`.

If you move it to the end, it'll loose its meaning as a range, that's why it works.

Comment: aah, so `\-` does not in fact escape a hyphen. Is there another way?

Comment: @jozxyqk replacing it at the beginning or end of the character class.