# Difference between grep -E regex and Bash regex in conditional expression

Tags: regex, bash

For the same regex applied to the same string, why does `grep -E` match, but the Bash `=~` operator in `[[ ]]` does not?

```
$ D=Dw4EWRwer
$ echo $D|grep -qE '^[A-Z][A-Za-z0-9]{1,2}[[:alnum:]_-\ ]{1,22}$' || echo wrong pattern
$ [[ "${D}" =~ ^[A-Z][A-Za-z0-9]{1,2}[[:alnum:]_-\ ]{1,22}$ ]] || echo wrong pattern
wrong pattern
```

Update: I confirm this worked:

```
[[ "${D}" =~ ^[A-Z][A-Za-z0-9]{1,2}[[:alnum:]\ _-]{1,22}$ ]] || echo wrong pattern
```

Comment: Because `[[ ]]` is evaluated by `bash` and the other command uses `grep`. Different programs, different `regex` flavours.

Comment: My `grep` tells me that this part `[[:alnum:]_-\ ]` is incorrect, namely the range from `_` to `\_` is invalid.

Comment: My `bash` tells me that `[[ "${D}" =~ ^[A-Z][A-Za-z0-9]{1,2}[[:alnum:]_-\ ]{1,22}$ ]]` returns exit code 2; that means the `regex` is incorrect.

Comment: You should probably write the range like this: `\ -_`, as `space` has lower ASCII code than `_`.

Comment: Do you actually want a range, or a literal `-` in your bracket expression?

Comment: They should both use Extended Regular Expressions, but in Bash, if you use it like this, you have to escape all special characters in the regex; the recommended way is to store the regex in a variable and then use the variable in `[[ ]]`.

Comment: To get a literal `-` inside a character class (`[...]`) you have to place it as the first or the last character.

Comment: If you want to match literal `-`, then consult this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28495913/how-do-you-escape-a-hypen-as-character-range-in-a-grep-regex

Comment: I need to find lines which begin with capital letter after which two of [a-zA-Z0-9] and then some words single space separated with possible _-, all together not longer that 25 chars

Answer (score 0):

The problem (for both versions of the code) is on this character class:

```
[[:alnum:]_-\ ]
```

In the `grep` version, because the `regex` is enclosed in single quotes, the backslash doesn't escape anything and the character range received by `grep` is exactly how it is represented above.

In the `bash` version, the backslash (`\`) escapes the space that follows it and the actual character class used by `[[ ]]` to test is `[[:alnum:]_- ]`.

Because in ASCII table the underscore (`_`) comes after both space () and backslash (`\`), neither of these character classes is correct.

For the `bash` version you can use:

```
[[ "${D}" =~ ^[A-Z][A-Za-z0-9]{1,2}[[:alnum:]_-\ ]{1,22}$ ]]; echo $?
```

to verify its outcome. If the `regex` is incorrect, the exit code is `2`.

---

If you want to put a dash (`-`) into a character class you have to put it either as the first character in the class (just after `[` or `[^` if it is a negating class) or as the last character in the class (`right before the closing`]`).

The `grep` version of the code should be (there is no need to escape anything inside a string enclosed in single quotes):

```
$ echo $D | grep -qE '^[A-Z][A-Za-z0-9]{1,2}[[:alnum:]_ -]{1,22}$' || echo wrong pattern
```

The `bash` version of your code should be:

```
[[ "${D}" =~ ^[A-Z][A-Za-z0-9]{1,2}[[:alnum:]_\ -]{1,22}$ ]] || echo wrong pattern
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, you want the bracket expression to contain alphanumeric characters, spaces, underscores and dashes, so the dash is not supposed to indicate a range. To add a hyphen to a bracket expression, it has to be the first or last character in it. Additionally, you don't have to escape things in bracket expressions, so you can drop the backslash. Your grep regex includes a literal `\` in the bracket expression:

```
$ grep -q '[\]' <<< '\' && echo "Match"
Match
```

In the Bash regex, the space has to be escaped because the string is first read by the shell, but see below how to avoid that.

First, fixing your regex:

```
^[A-Z][A-Za-z0-9]{1,2}[[:alnum:]_ -]{1,22}$
```

The backslash is gone, and the hyphen is moved to the end. Using this with grep works fine:

```
$ D=Dw4EWRwer
$ grep -E '^[A-Z][A-Za-z0-9]{1,2}[[:alnum:]_ -]{1,22}$' <<< "$D"
Dw4EWRwer
```

To use the regex within `[[ ]]` directly, the space has to be escaped:

```
$ [[ $D =~ ^[A-Z][A-Za-z0-9]{1,2}[[:alnum:]_\ -]{1,22}$ ]] && echo "Match"
Match
```

I would make the following changes:

- Use character classes where possible: `[A-Z]` is `[[:upper:]]`, `[A-Za-z0-9]` is `[[:alnum:]]`
- Store the regex in a variable for usage in `[[ ]]`; this has two advantages: no escaping characters special to the shell, and compatibility with older Bash versions, as the quoting requirements changed between 3.1 and 3.2 (see the [Patterns article](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Patterns) in the BashGuide).

The regex would then become this for grep:

```
$ grep -E '^[[:upper:]][[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]_ -]{1,22}$' <<< "$D"
Dw4EWRwer
```

and this in Bash:

```
$ re='^[[:upper:]][[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]_ -]{1,22}$'
$ [[ $D =~ $re ]] && echo "Match"
Match
```